# Reactor how to repeat some step n times if condition is met

Tags: project-reactor

Please help me with reactor
I need to check one condition max n times and return the final result after all

I found that reactor has reactor-extra module

https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/retry/Repeat.html

It has construction
`Repeat.create(java.util.function.Predicate<? super RepeatContext<T>> predicate, long n)`
Repeat function that repeats n times, only if the predicate returns true.

It looks like right solution, but I can't understand where should be
tha action, which I want to repeat?
I have Flux with many actions, but I want to repeat only one

Please make an example of code

Thank you

```
private int culculateNextResult(some params) {
          // some implementation  
 }



private Boolean compareResults(int prevRes, int nextRes) {
          // some implementation
 }

 public Flux<Boolean> run(some params, Flux<Integer> prevResults){

      return prevResults.map(elem -> compareResults(elem, culculateNextResult(some params)));

 // THIS LOGIC SHOULD BE REPEATED N times if compareResults(elem,       
 // culculateNextResult(some params))) == false, if true, we don't need 
// to repeat 
     }
```

I want to repeat compareResults(elem, culculateNextResult(some params))) until it's nit true. but n times maximum and return Flux as a result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Flux.repeat` and `Mono.repeat` will re-subscribe to the source, so every previous step of the source will be repeated with a new subscription.

Since `calculateNextResult` and `compareResults` are both synchronous operations in your example, you can use a simple `for` loop to repeat...

```java
    public Flux<Boolean> run(some params, Flux<Integer> prevResults){
        return prevResults.map(elem -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (compareResults(elem, calculateNextResult(some params))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
```

If `calculateNextResult` or `compareResults` were reactive methods returning `Mono`, then you could use `flatMap` instead of `map`, and use one of the `Mono.repeat*` methods.

For example, something like this:

```java
    private Mono<Integer> calculateNextResult(some params) {
        // some implementation
    }

    private Mono<Boolean> compareResults(int prevRes, int nextRes) {
        // some implementation
    }
    public Flux<Boolean> run(some params, Flux<Integer> prevResults){

        return prevResults.flatMap(prevResult -> 

            calculateNextResult(some params)
                    .flatMap(nextResult -> compareResults(prevResult, nextResult))
                    .filter(comparisonResult -> comparisonResult)
                    .repeatWhenEmpty(Repeat.times(5))
                    .defaultIfEmpty(false));
    }
```

In this example, the `repeatWhenEmpty` will cause a new subscription to the Mono created within the flatMap, which will cause `calculateNextResult` to recalculate (assuming the Mono returned from `calculateNextResult` is setup to calculate a value on every subscription).